# Proof of generalization of a particular limit converging to $e^{\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}}$

Tags: analysis, limits, logarithms, exponentiation

I was reading a very old and long article on logarithms in a library it has pages turned yellow and had one pages titled  - **Tricky problems** I managed to solve 5 out of the 6 but I couldn't do this 6th one . Prove that for all $ p \in \mathbb{N}$ - $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{(1^{1^p} \times  2^{2^p} \times 3^{3^p}  \times    \ldots n^{n ^p}  )}{n^{\frac{1}{p+1}}} =e^{\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}}$$
I tried to manupilate this with the properties of logarithms but failed.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The value in the limit is as least $n^{n^p-\frac{1}{p+1}}\to\infty$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{N}$ include $0$? Because $p=0$ gives you $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-1) ! = e$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So it's true for $p=1$ :P

Comment: No, not even for $p=1$ - then the terms are bounded below by $n^{n-1/2}$, which diverges as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be wrong. The logarithm of the lhs is $$\text{HurwitzZeta}^{(1,0)}(-p,n+1)-\frac{\log (n)}{p+1}-\zeta '(-p)$$ which goes to infinity with $n$

Comment: We don't know for sure, but it seems unlikely that the OP knows what the Hurwitz Zeta is, and it's much easier to show it diverges.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you tell me what OP is?

Comment: OP=original poster, a common acronym here when talking about the person who wrote the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if its so then I may tell you that I do know a lot of thing about the Hurwitz Zeta functions , I am working on continued fractions related to it .But what you say is equally true that divergence can be shown quite easily.

Comment: @ShivamPatel. Good to know. Cheers.